# Adding a "three line" character (☰) or image to TB Mega Menu dropdown button

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I'm currently developing a website with TB Mega Menu using a Zen subtheme. The problem is that the default TB Mega Menu button (the one that replaces the 'normal' horizontal menu on smaller screens) is just an empty white button without any signs. I want to make it more understandable for users by adding an industry-standart "three line" character (☰) or an image. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

element:before {content: "☰";} should do the trick. I'm seeing some other problem in there actually. The presence of `<i></i>` element means there should be a font icon on load, with the i:before reacting as your three bars. Sirate theme, for example, doesn't have it, so it has to be a bug.

Could you provide a live site so we could give you a solution based on it? TB Megamenu could be different as markup depending on the theme. Or your CSS could be changed, based on some Zen stuff.